# download image and show in activity in android

Tags: android

I am having urls of images.
I am creating .JPEG files of it and saving in a directory of SD card.

After downloading all images (creating bitmaps and compressing in JPEG), i am calling another intent, which is supposed to show all images downloaded in that directory.

but I am seeing blank.

I cheecked DDMS, and found jpeg of correct sizes have got downloaded in my desired directory. But my intent is not showing.

To my surprise, when I close emulator , restart it, re run program with another set of image links, now my intent is showing previously downloaded images ! (not the images which r downloaded in this run of program).

Following is code i use for showing downloaded images:
Can anybody help me with this ?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.imagechooser);


        Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        thumbNailsLnkdhs = (LinkedHashSet<String>) bundle.getSerializable("keyThumbNails");

         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                 "ThumbNailsLnkdhs size in new intent: "+thumbNailsLnkdhs.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
        final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;


        Cursor imagecursor=managedQuery( MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                columns, 
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " like ? ",
                    new String[] {"%myDesiredDirectory%"},  
                    null);

        Log.d(LOGGER, "cursor made");
        int colcount=imagecursor.getColumnCount();
        //.d(LOGGER, "cursor column count is: "+colcount);

        int count =imagecursor.getCount();
        //Log.d(LOGGER, "count is: "+count);

        String colnAME=imagecursor.getColumnName(0);
        //Log.d(LOGGER, "COL NAME FOR 0TH COLUMN="+colnAME);
        String colnAME_1=imagecursor.getColumnName(1);
        //Log.d(LOGGER, "COL NAME FOR 1st COLUMN="+colnAME_1);


        int image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(imagecursor.getColumnName(1));
        //Log.d(LOGGER, "image_column_index="+image_column_index);

        //Log.d(LOGGER, "ThumbNailsLnkdhs size: "+ThumbNailsLnkdhs.size());

        //int image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);


        this.count = imagecursor.getCount();
        //Log.d(LOGGER, "this.count="+this.count);

        this.thumbnails = new Bitmap[this.count];
        this.arrPath = new String[this.count];
        this.thumbnailsselection = new boolean[this.count];

        for (int i = 0; i < this.count; i++) {
            imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
            int id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
            int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            //Log.d(LOGGER, "dataColumnIndex="+dataColumnIndex);

            thumbnails[i] = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                    getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id,
                    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);

            arrPath[i]= imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
        }
        GridView imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneImageGrid);
        imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();
        imagegrid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
        imagecursor.close();
    }
```

ok, so as per suggestion of below ansr,
I found I need to insert image  in gallery after I create its physical file.

I tried

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmapimage,
imgname+ ".jpg Card Image", "imgDescription"
+ ".jpg Card Image");
```

but couldnt use getcontentresolver as im in a class which downloads,creates physical file and not inn activity.

So I tried

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"
                +Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        + "/myDesiredDirectory/")))
```

in my activity which displays previously downloaded images ... but it didnt helped me to show newly downloaded images... 
 so tried

```
  sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"

                + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+)));

    this also not showing new images :(
```

Can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

when you put Image manually in AVD through DDMS, you need to scan media from settings right?

same problem here

After download you need to scan media via coding and close the image cursor before set adapter.

Comment: thanks ! any idea how to scan  only that particular directory ?

Comment: Now I am searching for a way to scan a particular direcctory from my activity.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new ImageAdapter and then attaching the GridView to that 'new' adapter. In other words your GridView is bound to be empty as it is attached to a new blank adapter.

Where are you connecting the Bitmaps/Cursor to the Adapter/View?